# regex in javascript to remove numeric path from url

Tags: javascript, regex, string, url

I have URLs like below with customer ID etc. I want to remove them and put an asterisk instead of them.  Below examples will give you a better idea.

```
/paas/service/3.0/part/d878bc1e-9bb8-4a0e/log/account/7367c100-9390-11e3/resource/AdminHistory --> /paas/service/3.0/part/*/log/account/*/resource/AdminHistory

/hs/service/3.0/bootstrap/mnd/3388959354 --> /hs/service/3.0/bootstrap/mnd/*

/paas/service/3.0/part/d878bc1e-9bb8-4a0e-b224-a4ba0d7dfcec/asset --> /paas/service/3.0/part/*/asset

/paas/service/3.0/part/3c5631df-52c9/servicepolicy/8ee6ba08-8d7a/carrierPlan/c2b4a364-98e3-4546 --> /paas/service/3.0/part/*/servicepolicy/*/carrierPlan/*
```

The IDs are either numeric or alphanumeric. How should i approach this ?

Comment: You can just do something like: `url.replace(new RegExp(id, 'g'), '*')`.

Answer (score 1):

> *The IDs are either numeric or alphanumeric.*

*All* of the parts in your example URLs contain either letters or digits, so you need to know what the text is *before* the ID so that you can target that plus the ID that follows.

So perhaps something like this:

```js
function modifyURL(url) {
  return url.replace(/(\/(?:part|account|mnd|servicepolicy|carrierPlan)\/)[^\/]+/g, "$1*");
}

console.log(modifyURL("/paas/service/3.0/part/d878bc1e-9bb8-4a0e/log/account/7367c100-9390-11e3/resource/AdminHistory"));
console.log(modifyURL("/hs/service/3.0/bootstrap/mnd/3388959354"));
console.log(modifyURL("/paas/service/3.0/part/d878bc1e-9bb8-4a0e-b224-a4ba0d7dfcec/asset"));
console.log(modifyURL("/paas/service/3.0/part/3c5631df-52c9/servicepolicy/8ee6ba08-8d7a/carrierPlan/c2b4a364-98e3-4546"));
```

To explain the regex I've used:

```
(       // start of capturing submatch         
\/      // match a forward slash
(?:     // start of non-capturing group       
part|account|mnd|servicepolicy|carrierPlan   // match one of those words
)       // end of non-capturing group
\/      // match forward slash
)       // end of capturing submatch
[^\/]+  // match one or more of anything but a forward slash
```